# change the css according to theme and remove previous theme css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the functionality to add the css file of the theme according to user selection and remove the previous selected theme.css file. I have written this code

```
var previousTheme="theme1";
var show='theme1';
$(document.body).on('change', '#selecttheme', function () {
    show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
    $("#hue-demo-bg-div").fadeToggle("3000", function(){
        $("#hue-demo-bg-div").removeClass(previousTheme).addClass(show).css('background-color',"");
        $(document.head).find('#themecss').attr("href","/assets/css/"+show+".css");
        $('#heading_preview').css('color',"");
        $('#description_preview').css('color',"");
        $('#btn_text_preview').css('color',"");
        $('#hue-demo-link-div').css('background-color',"");
        $('#paragraph_preview').css('color',"");
        $('#decline_preview').css('color',"");
        $('#leadsnowheader').css('background-color',"");
   });
   previousTheme=show;
   $("#hue-demo-bg-div").fadeToggle("3000", function(){
         loadColorValues();
   });
});
```

This code is working fine on localhost. but on server it not working properly. It takes to much time to load the css. Any help or improvement in this code..?

Comment: Is it feasible to keep all css in one file?

Comment: No actually for all the themes we have a separate theme.css file. i have to load a specific theme.css file on select dropdown change

Comment: Why can it not be in 1 file? do they have contradicting styling? where are you removing the previous css file in your above code?

Comment: Sorry, i am not removing the css, only changes the href attribute of the link given in head tag based on id

Comment: How big is your CSS file? Try minimizing it. use browser debugger and check what is taking time

Comment: not sure, but you can try removing the `#themecss` element itself and then inserting it again with new `href`. Perhaps that might trigger browser earlier than an `href` change. Otherwise, the time to load the new css should be same for both approaches.

Comment: They cannot be in a single file as I understand, they are different themes with same classname containing different styles

Comment: i checked there, it only takes the request time. my css file is in between 4-6Kb

Comment: yeah, exactly having same classes for each theme but diffrent style attributes

Comment: I mean if the css in one file is a option then you I would run the theme by having a body class, and have styles nested, `.theme-one .some-header {...}` ect... if you are doing scss that is even more simple. This way you can switch the theme in a instant with just changing the body class.

Comment: in my theme each and every elment is dynamic which user can change, like change the header text, color, header-background color, body-color, body text color, body background image. So i have to mange each and every thing. So wrapping all the things also not possible. I have to also show the same customized theme using single scrip which will be loaded on other sites during campaigning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite everything in plain JavaScript. Then minify the file. Also, minify all CSS files that should be loaded. Also, `.change(function(){});` is faster than `.on('change', function() {});`

I know it increases readability when putting everything in `variables`, but letting `jQuery` to loop through the system of elements to find the `variables` decreases the time.

Now, there are many factors on the server side which can affect this. I do not even know where to start...